# Compiler errors on partial template speciailzation (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I am trying to do a simple partial template specialization, but I get errors on g++4.4.7, g++4.8.5, clang++3.8.0. Whenever I mention compiler(s) error, I mean the output of all of these, as they always agree.
I am using C++03, compiling without any option.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename X, typename G>
struct A {};

template <typename T, typename X>
struct A<T, X, void> { A() : n(1) {} X n; T b; };

template <typename X>
struct A<X, void, void> { A() : n(2) {} X n; };

int main() {
  A<int, float> one;
  A<int> two;
  std::cout << one.n << " | " << two.n << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

**Question 1:** This code fails to compile. The compilers say that `A<int, float>` and `A<int>` are wrong as `A` requires 3 templates parameters. Why?

If I change the original declaration to

```
template <typename T, typename X = void, typename G = void>
struct A {};
```

The code compiles and the output is: `1 | 2`.

What happens is that the compiler in a first step matches `one` and `two` type to the not specialized `A`,  but then it correctly decides to use the code of the partially specialized class one would expect it to use. But it should not need the defaults.

I then decide to change the last partial specialization switching the first and second parameter:

```
template <typename X>
struct A<void, X, void> { A() : n(2) {} X n; };
```

I would expect this to change nothing, but the compilers disagree. The clearest output between the 3 is here reported:

```
a.cpp:7:40: error: field has incomplete type 'void'
struct A<T, X, void> { A() : n(1) {} X n; T b; };
                                   ^
a.cpp:14:10: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<int, void, void>'    requested here
  A<int> two;
         ^
1 error generated.
```

**Question 2:** Why are the compilers considering the `two` variable an instance of the partial specialization of A that specializes only one argument?

Note that is the "2nd matching", because if I only use 1 default template argument, the compiler will go back to complaining about the fact that 3 template parameters are needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Template specialization only tells the compiler to use a specific implementation when **you specify** a specific set of arguments, it does not allow the compiler to choose a template (what would happens if you add two specialization with `<X, void, void>` and `<X, int, int>`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question 1: This code fails to compile. The compilers say that `A<int, float>` and `A<int>` are wrong as `A` requires 3 templates parameters. Why?

Because `A` requires 3 template parameters. You declared `A` as:

```
template <typename T, typename X, typename G>
struct A {};
```

There is no two- or one-template parameter version of `A`. There are versions specialized on some of the types being `void`, but that's still a parameter - not an absence of parameter.

When you add the defaults, then `A<int, float>` evaluates as `A<int, float, void>`, which is a valid instantiation - and picks the specialization which sets `n` to 1.

You're misunderstanding how specialization works. Specialization doesn't change the number of template parameters. It's just a way of adding special functionality depending on what the template parameters end up being.

> Question 2: Why are the compilers considering the two variable an instance of the partial specialization of `A` that specializes only one argument?

We have three choices

```
template <T, X, G>       struct A; // the primary
template <T, X, void>    struct A; // (1)
template <void, X, void> struct A; // (2)
```

When we instantiate `A<int>`, that is the same as `A<int, void, void>` when we add in the default parameters. That does not match `(2)` - because that one requires the first parameter to be `void` and yours is `int`. `(1)` is a better match than the primary since it's more specialized. But then, `(1)` has a member of type `X` and in this case `X` is deduced as `void` (from the default parameter), and that's not allowed.